# Axios stripe issues. "invalid_request_error"

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, axios

I am at my wits end! I am trying to create a customer via the stripe api. Using their example with curl i have no problems. 
Here is their example:

`curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers \
   -u sk_test_apikey: \
   -d description="Customer for zoey.brown@example.com" \
   -d source=tok_visa`

It is when i try to do this with axios that i get an error "invalid_request_error" because it isn't properly parsing my data. Here's what i've got:

```
export const registerNewUser = async (firstName, lastName, email, password) => {
  let config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${stripeTestApiKey}`
    }
  }
  let data = {
      email: `${email}`,
      description: `Customer account for ${email}`
  }
  await axios.post(stripeCustomerUri, data, config)
    .then(res => {
      console.log("DEBUG-axios.post--res: ", res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
    })
}
```

and in my console i see that stripe isn't receiving my data in the correct manner. Here's the (useful part of my) response json:

```
"response": { 
  "data": { 
    "error": { 
      "type": "invalid_request_error", 
      "message": "Received unknown parameter: {\"email\":\"joe@blow.com\",\"description\":\"Customer account for joe@blow.com\"}", "param": "{\"email\":\"joe@blow.com\",\"description\":\"Customer account for joe@blow.com\"}" } },
```

Judging by all of my other attempts and this example error, I am not passing my data in the correct format... However, when i pass `-d` to my curl command everything works as expected... If I send an empty string as `data` it works as well...

does anyone have an idea why / how this is? How is the "data" object via curl differ from my javascript data object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that axios uses application/json content type by default and the stripe api requires form-url-encoded... this requires parsing the data object with a library like querystring before passing through to the stripe api... hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This issue really bugged me. For more info, read https://github.com/axios/axios ('Using application/x-www-form-urlencoded format') section.